# java VirtualMachine.getSystemProperties() deadlock

Tags: java, api, jvm, deadlock

i'm using the Java Attach API to connect to local JVMs. i'm doing something like the following

```
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("8400");
Properties props = vm.getSystemProperties();
```

running on a windows machine, if the VirtualMachine i am connecting to is shutdown between the attach and the getSystemProperties calls, `getSystemProperties()` will block forever and create a deadlock in that thread. i've traced the block down to `WindowsVirtualMachine.connectPipe()`. it's a native method, so in the WindowsVirtualMachine.c connectPipe function there is a call to ConnectNamedPipe. i've seen a few posts about ConnectNamedPipe deadlocking on Windows machines. i've tried interrupting the thread that is blocked, but that does not unblock the thread.

i'm not quite sure what the workaround is for this, but i would consider not using the Attach API (although i prefer to stick with my current solution). i'm using the Attach API to use `VirtualMachine.list()` to get the JVMs running on the local machine. and then from there i am using that to get system properties and connect to them via JMX. i know i could probably create a custom solution using a library to communicate between the processes over the network, but i'd rather use os level communication between the processes, which is what i believe the Attach API is using.

so my question is are there any workarounds for my issue? or are there any libraries that could give me the same functionality as `VirtualMachine.list()`?

Comment: What do you mean interrupting the thread does not work? it does nothing?

Comment: interrupting the thread that is blocked does not unblock it.

Comment: Also try to stop() the thread (which BTW is a bad idea, but see how it behaves). Here is the doc for interrupt: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29

Comment: Can you show what you were doing to interrupt?

Answer (score 0):

what would you want to happen in this case?  A common solution for a problem like this is to have a watcher thread that waits for the thread to finish a task and then if it doesn't finish it in some amount of time assume there is a deadlock and exit the process.  Obviously this is pretty heavy handed but there is not much else you could do in this case that would be 'correct'.